# Determine customers that have spent money at the company for the first time, each month (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a table below and I am trying to determine the number of users that have spent money at the company for the first time each month.

What I would like is to have a resulting table with new users, month and year as columns.

**Before people downvote this post, I have looked through various posts already and can't seem to find a similar way to solve this issue. The code that I have included below is based on what I've managed to piece together from relevant posts.**

This is the original table:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| datetime            | customer_id | amount          |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2018-03-01 03:00:00 | 3786        | 14              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2018-03-02 17:00:00 | 5678        | 25              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2018-08-17 19:00:00 | 5267        | 45              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2018-08-25 08:00:00 | 3456        | 78              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2018-08-25 17:00:00 | 3456        | 25              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019-05-25 14:00:00 | 3456        | 15              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019-07-02 14:00:00 | 88889       | 45              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019-08-25 08:00:00 | 1234        | 88              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019-08-30 09:31:00 | 1234        | 30              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019-08-30 12:00:00 | 9876        | 55              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019-09-01 13:00:00 | 88889       | 23              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

This is the CREATE statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spend` ( `datetime` datetime NOT NULL, `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `amount` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`datetime`)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-03-01 03:00:00', 3786, 14);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-03-02 17:00:00', 5678, 25);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-17 19:00:00', 5267, 45);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-25 08:00:00', 3456, 78);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2018-08-25 17:00:00', 3456, 25);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-05-25 14:00:00', 3456, 15);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-07-02 14:00:00', 88889, 45);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-08-25 08:00:00', 1234, 88);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-08-30 09:31:00', 1234, 30);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-08-30 12:00:00', 9876, 55);
INSERT INTO `spend` (`datetime`, `customer_id`, `amount`) VALUES ('2019-09-01 13:00:00', 88889, 23);
```

This is the code that I have come up with:

```
SELECT S.datetime, S.customer_id, S.amount 
FROM spend S
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT customer_id, MIN(datetime) AS first_occurence
    FROM spend
    GROUP BY customer_id) X
ON S.customer_id = X.customer_id AND S.datetime = X.first_occurence
```

This is the resulting table:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| datetime         | customer_id |amount |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 01/03/2018 03:00 | 3786        | 14    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 02/03/2018 17:00 | 5678        | 25    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 17/08/2018 19:00 | 5267        | 45    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 25/08/2018 08:00 | 3456        | 78    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 02/07/2019 14:00 | 88889       | 45    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 25/08/2019 08:00 | 1234        | 88    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
| 30/08/2019 12:00 | 9876        | 55    |
+------------------+-------------+-------+
```

This is what an example of what the table should look like:

```
+-----------+-------+------+
| new_users | month | year |
+-----------+-------+------+
| 2         | 3     | 2018 |
+-----------+-------+------+
| 3         | 8     | 2018 |
+-----------+-------+------+
| 1         | 5     | 2019 |
+-----------+-------+------+
| 1         | 7     | 2019 |
+-----------+-------+------+
| 3         | 8     | 2019 |
+-----------+-------+------+
| 1         | 9     | 2019 |
+-----------+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started correctly. Now use that as a subquery to get the count by month.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS new_users, MONTH(datetime) AS month, YEAR(datetime) AS year
FROM (
    SELECT S.datetime, S.customer_id, S.amount 
    FROM spend S
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT customer_id, MIN(datetime) AS first_occurence
        FROM spend
        GROUP BY customer_id) X
    ON S.customer_id = X.customer_id AND S.datetime = X.first_occurence
) AS x
GROUP BY month, year
ORDER BY year, month
```

Actually, you don't even need the join in the subquery, since you're not using the amount from the first purchase in the final result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS new_users, MONTH(datetime) AS month, YEAR(datetime) AS year
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, MIN(datetime) AS datetime
    FROM spend
    GROUP BY customer_id
) AS x
GROUP BY month, year
ORDER BY year, month
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! That makes much more sense now and it works perfectly :D

Answer (score 1):

You dont need two levels deep subquery. You can simply find the first time a customer spent money using `MIN()` and then simply extract `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` out of that minimum datetime value, to count number of users:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(min_dt) y,
  MONTH(min_dt) m,
  COUNT(*) AS new_customers 
FROM 
(
  SELECT customer_id, MIN(datetime) AS min_dt 
  FROM spend 
  GROUP BY customer_id 
) t
GROUP BY y, m
```

**Result**

```
| y    | m   | new_customers |
| ---- | --- | ------------- |
| 2018 | 3   | 2             |
| 2018 | 8   | 2             |
| 2019 | 7   | 1             |
| 2019 | 8   | 2             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/37YEZYhzJGtSTtPgwXHMpj/0)

Answer (score 0):

With ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
select 
  count(*) new_users,
  month(t.datetime) month,
  year(t.datetime) year
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by datetime) rn
  from spend
) t
where t.rn = 1
group by year, month
order by year, month
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tLrVvEeNARnmBHme4yxRMr/0) for your sample data.
Results:

```
| new_users | month | year |
| --------- | ----- | ---- |
| 2         | 3     | 2018 |
| 2         | 8     | 2018 |
| 1         | 7     | 2019 |
| 2         | 8     | 2019 |
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
select   
count(*) new_users,
month(datetime) month,
year(datetime) year
from spend
where datetime in (select min(datetime) from spend group by customer_id)
group by year, month
order by year, month;
```